# some parts of my 3D stick figure can't be presented

Tags: graphics, 3d, xna

I am developing a 3D game based on Microsoft XNA framwork 4.0 in C#. To display a 3D stick figure, I am using meshes such as cylinder.fbx and load it like this this.cylinderMesh = this.Game.Content.Load("Meshes\Cylinder"); But the problem is that when I turning around the stick figure, some part can't not be showed. I post my screenshot here:

[image]

I think it might be something related to camera distance causing some parts in the back cannot display. Is my guess right or where the problem is?

Comment: Where you create your projection matrix, try to increase the far plane value. That should be the last parameter to `CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView (
         float fieldOfView,
         float aspectRatio,
         float nearPlaneDistance,
         float farPlaneDistance
)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to modify the last parameter to 10,000. But the result was the same, really disappointed. I think it should be within the area between nearPlaneDistance  and farPlaneDistance. oh, I am also using a Effect Shaders which loads 3DEffects.fx. Do you think the problem is caused by some effects that obscure parts of the stick figure from the camera.

Comment: Thank you @Niko Drašković, I have fixed the problem. I modified the translation matrix with positive Z Axis value. Even though it works now, I still don't know why it does not work when I just use larger farPlaneDistance. Any way, thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe you could try scaling your models down. Might be that the entire scene is too big.